# How to apply something like --space-prototype-paren=0 but for signatures with perltidy

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

We have the following code:

```
sub some_method($self, %args) {
    #code here
}
```

When I run it trough perltidy it gets formatted like this:

```
sub some_method ($self, %args) {
    #code here
}
```

How to make perltidy to not add the space between the subroutine name and the starting parenthesis for the signature?
I looked at the perltidy [documentation](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/view/bin/perltidy) but the closest I found was `--space-prototype-paren=0` which seemingly does not work for signatures.

Comment: Signatures are an experimental feature. They are probably not covered by perltidy. I would say that an extra space is not that big a deal. Certainly Perl will not notice.

Comment: You could perhaps [raise a ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Perl-Tidy) asking for this to be added.

Comment: If you in Linux/Unix try to use [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) - vim support formatting and code coloring. To re-indent for example whole perl script sufficient in command mode type `gg=G`. Although different people prefer different code styles. It was indicated already **Signature** is _experimental_ feature which is not supported in may editors/tools.